# Cannot resolve symbol '@android:color/white'

Tags: android, xml, flutter

I'm having this issue while creating a splash screen in flutter. I looked for an answer but no one solve the matter or answer perfectly.

> Cannot resolve symbol '@android:color/black'

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create StateFulWidget

Add one Future.delayed() to initstate.

```
@override
     void initState() {
        super.initState();

        Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 3), () {
          Navigator.of(context).push(
            MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => const SecondScreen(),
            ),
          );
        });
      }
```

Duration(seconds:3) will wait for 3 seconds on the splash screen then it will redirect to SecondScreen.

the code should be like this

```
    class SplashScreen extends StatefulWidget {
      const SplashScreen({super.key});
    
      @override
      State<SplashScreen> createState() => _SplashScreenState();
    }
    
    class _SplashScreenState extends State<SplashScreen> {
      @override
      void initState() {
        super.initState();
        Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 3), () {
          Navigator.of(context).push(
            MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => const SecondScreen(),
            ),
          );
        });
      }
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          body: Container(
            color: Colors.blue,
            child: const Center(child: Text("Splash Screen")),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

the whole code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const SplashScreen(),
    );
  }
}

class SplashScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const SplashScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<SplashScreen> createState() => _SplashScreenState();
}

class _SplashScreenState extends State<SplashScreen> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 3), () {
      Navigator.of(context).push(
        MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => const SecondScreen(),
        ),
      );
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        color: Colors.blue,
        child: const Center(child: Text("Splash Screen")),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class SecondScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const SecondScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<SecondScreen> createState() => _SecondScreenState();
}

class _SecondScreenState extends State<SecondScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        color: Colors.green,
        child: const Center(
          child: Text("Home Screen"),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

If it was useful, you can choose it as an approved answer and give points. Good coding.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this,

```
<item android:background="@android:color/white" />
```

When it comes to drawable you should assign XMLs or images in your drawable or mipmap resource

Comment: I already did that, but its not working, thanks for Your time & answer